# Tensorboard scalars and graphs duplicated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using TensorBoard to visualize network metrics and graph.

I create a session `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` and build the graph in Jupyter notebook.

In the graph, I include two summary scalars:

```
with tf.variable_scope('summary') as scope:    
   loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Loss', cross_entropy)
   train_accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Train_accuracy', accuracy)
```

I then create a `summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, sess.graph)` and run:

`_,loss_sum,train_accuracy_sum=sess.run([...],feed_dict=feed_dict)`

I write the metrics:

```
summary_writer.add_summary(loss_sum, i)
summary_writer.add_summary(train_accuracy_sum, i)
```

I run the code three times.

Each time I run, I re-import TF and create a new interactive session.

But, in Tensorboard, a separate scalar window is created for each run:

[image]

Also, the graph appears to be duplicated if I check data for the last run:

[image]

How do I prevent duplication of the graph and scalar window each time I run?

- I want all data to appear in the same scalar plots (with multiple series / plot).
- I want each run to reference a single graph visualization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the problem arises because you are running the code three times in the process (same script, Jupyter notebook, or whatever), and those invocations share the same ["default graph"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_graph) in TensorFlow. TensorFlow needs to give each node in the graph a unique name, so it appends `"_1"` and `"_2"` to the names of the summary nodes in the second and third invocations.

How do you avoid this? The easiest way is to create a new graph each time you run the code. There are (at least) three ways to do this:

- Wrap the code in a [`with tf.Graph().as_default():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#as_default) block, which constructs a new [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) object and sets it is the default graph for the extent of the `with` block.
- If you construct your session *before* creating the graph, you can construct your session as `sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=tf.Graph())`. The newly constructed `tf.Graph` object remains as the default graph until you call `sess.close()`.
- Call [`tf.reset_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph) between invocations of the code.

The `with`-block approach is the "most structured" way to do things, and might be best if you are writing a standalone script. However, since you are using [`tf.InteractiveSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession), I assume you are using an interactive REPL of some kind, and the other two approaches are probably more useful (e.g. for splitting the execution across multiple cells).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the issue :) Running from Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I went with option #2: `sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=tf.Graph()) `

Comment: Will this create a lot of burden too? In the sense that each time you're creating a new graph?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs to hold multiple graphs its not a problem if you want to solve this use:

tf.reset_default_graph()