# How do I "reset" the graph displayed in TensorBoard for a TensroFlow InteractiveSession?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'd like to be able to view a TensorFlow graph that I'm experimenting with in a TensorBoard `InteractiveSession`.

For example I'd like to be ale to enter an operation `A` and then refresh TensorBoard and see `A` in the graph, then execute `B` and refresh and see `B` in the graph. Then if I decide I want to change the graph, I'd like to preform some operation and get a clean slate, so that when I subsequently enter `A` and `C`, I just see `A` and `C` in TensorBoard, and not `B`, `C` and two versions of `A`, as I currently see.

For example if I

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# operation A
# operation B
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=sess.graph)
writer.flush()
```

and then run

```
tensorboard --logdir logdir --purge_orphaned_data
```

I get a graph in TensorBoard showing `A` an `B` as expected.

If I later perform additional operations

```
# operation P
# operation Q
```

these do not appear in TensorBoard, unless I again execute:

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='_tflog', graph=sess.graph)
writer.flush()
```

which creates a *new log* and `P` and `Q` now appear in the graph alongside `A` and `B` in TensorBoard.

Each additional execution of any of these operations either has no effect in TensorBoard, or appears as an additional node if I run the `writer` lines above.

If I want to subsequently remove operations (say `A` and `P`), I seem to need to completely restart everything (the `Session` and the `FileWriter` and delete all the old logs).

All this is confusing and hard to keep track of (I'm not even certain my account above is accurate!).

Is there some way to completely reset the `Graph` that TensorBoard uses so that I can view in TensorBoard only those graph elements added since the last such reset?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new, so FWIW: I think part of the issue is with the Graph not the Session.

TF seems to have a very sticky Default Graph.

In a *non-interactive* setting, I had to do two main things to:

1) get rid of old Session file(s) (events.out.tfevents....) each time so they did not pile up, and

2) really clear the Graph (by using something other than the hidden Default Graph in my Session) to overwrite the tensorboard display.

Note that is seems fine to keep tensorboard running and just refresh the localhost:6006 URL in the web browser.

Around my main Graph construction code, I use a:

```
mytfgraph = tf.Graph() # Get something other than the Default Graph
with mytfgraph.asdefault():

    ...lots of good code here...

    # Get rid of old Tensorboard graph file and just save new one
    filesindir = os.listdir(your_graph_location) 
    # os. calls may be OS-dependent
    # Make sure there is no subdir as not checking for this!
    for file in filesindir:
        try:        
            delfile = graph_location + file
            os.remove(delfile)
         except: 
             print('Warning, Tensorboard file not removed')

    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_location)
    # Using custom graph as default ("the with wrapper above")
    train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph()) 
    train_writer.close()

    ...down here I run batches using a 'with tf.Session() as sess:'...
```

There is an alternate for the Graph part that may simplify your life since you are using an Interactive session (which I don't know much about). That is the private method: `tf.reset_default_graph()`. [Tensorboard scalars and graphs duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847155/tensorboard-scalars-and-graphs-duplicated?rq=1)

Hacky or not, I did not use this since I wanted to try using only public methods.